# C# Log4Net File from yesterday not appearing but 2+ days ago files do appear

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

In my c# app, I am using a log4net file appender to write logs (one file per day). I can see today's logs and I can see 2+ days ago logs but I cannot see yesterdays logs for some reason.

Example: Today is 2-8. I am able to see the logs written for 2-8 and 2-6,2-5,2-4 and so on but I cannot see yesterdays logs (2-7). When tomorrow rolls around, I will be able to see 2-7's logs but not 2-8s logs.

I have confirmed that yesterday's logs are not being written to today's log file.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Here is my log4net code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net debug="false">

  <!--Driver service logging -->
  <appender name="DriverLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="D:\Logs\" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="45" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <logger additivity="false" name="DriverService">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="DriverLog" />
  </logger>
  <!--end Driver service logging -->


</log4net>
```

I am giving the log4net file a name programatically like so:

```
String logFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("LogFolder");
String appName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("AppName");
var appenders = LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders();
foreach (var appender in appenders)
{
    var logger = (log4net.Appender.FileAppender)appender;
    String fileName = logger.Name + ".txt";
    logger.File = $"{logFolder}{env}\\{appName}\\{fileName}";
    logger.ActivateOptions();
}
```

I have tried researching this problem but am not having any luck identifying the issue.